# prove the trigonometry identity:

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

prove the trigonometry identity:

> $$\tan^4(A) = \frac{\tan^3(A) + \frac{1 - \tan(A)}{\cot(A)}}{\frac{1 - \cot(A)}{\tan(A)} + \cot^3(A)}$$

of course i started from the complicated side the RHS and i wrote them all into tangents but then it all messy up and I'm stuck there.

Comment: I have tried to rewrite your identity with proper formatting. Please leave a comment or edit your question appropriately if there's anything that I misinterpreted

Comment: The identity seems false. When $A=0$, the left-hand side equals $0$ but the right-hand side is $1$ divided by a function that's unbounded near $A=0$.

Comment: is it $1-\frac{\tan A}{\cot A}$ or $\frac{1-\tan A}{\cot A}$?

Comment: the second fraction is correct Ak19

Answer (score 3):

> $1.  \ \cot^3A = \dfrac{1}{\tan^3A}\\$
> $2.  \ \dfrac{1-\cot A}{\tan A } = \dfrac1{\tan A}-\dfrac{1}{\tan^2A}\\$
> $3. \  \dfrac{1-\tan A}{\cot A} = \tan A - \tan^2A$

So, the RHS becomes,

$\begin{align}\dfrac{\tan^3A + \tan A - \tan^2A}{\dfrac1{\tan A}-\dfrac{1}{\tan^2A} +\dfrac{1}{\tan^3A}} &= \dfrac{\tan^3A + \tan A - \tan^2A}{\dfrac{1}{\tan^3A}\left(\tan^2A-\tan A+1\right)} \\&= \tan^3A\dfrac{\tan A(\tan^2A+1-\tan A)}{\tan^2A+1-\tan A} \\&= \tan^4A\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\tan(A)$.

Multiply both sides by rhs denominator and let $\cot(A)=1/t$. Then lhs $=t^4(1-1/t)(1/t)+t=t^3-t^2+t$, while rhs $=t^3+(1-t)t=t^3+t-t^2$.

Therefore equality.

Answer (score 2):

$$t^4\left(\dfrac{1 -t^{-1}}{t} +t^{-3}\right)=t^3 + \dfrac{1 - t}{t^{-1}}$$
is

$$t^3-t^2+t=t^3+t-t^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll begin by saying that when you want to prove an identity like $ L=R $  you **cannot** multiply both sides by any value, since then it wouldn't be an identity.

Anyway, Lets say that $L$ is LHS, and $R$ is RHS. Let $t=\tan(A)$. We can then say that $\frac{1}{t}=\cot(A)$.

Therefore, RHS becomes
$$ R = \frac{t^3 + \frac{1-t}{\frac{1}{t}}}{\frac{1-\frac{1}{t}}{t} + \frac{1}{t^3}} $$

Simplifying the top and bottom (separately) shows us that

$$ R = \frac{t^3-t^2+t}{\frac{t-1}{t^2} + \frac{1}{t^3}}$$

Multiply the top and bottom by $ t^3 $, then

$$ R = \frac{t^3(t^3-t^2+t)}{t(t-1)+1} = \frac{t^4(t^2-t+1)}{t^2-t+1} = t^4 $$

Then, substituting back $ t=\tan(A) $, we get

$$ R = \tan^4(A) = L $$

Like we wanted.